# React Native cannot run default android

Tags: react-native

I am doing the following and not sure why default application not working

```
c:\Mob\react-native init MyTest
c:\Mob\cd MyTest
c:\Mob\react-native run-android
```

I can see that the android app is pushed over to my virtual device. But why am I getting this error ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Metro is still running in the background. It is serving the old cache. Hence, we can kill it by killing the nodejs project. In windows, we can issue

```
taskkill /F /IM node.exe
```